# Qual a melhor forma de salvar dados em tempo real?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados

Galera, vocês podem me dizer qual é a melhor forma para salvar dados em tempo real?
Por exemplo, eu tenho um portal de notícias e preciso salvar cada acesso que recebo e mostrar em um painel privado, mas no caso meu site possuí 30 mil pessoas simultâneas executando um script que salvar as visitas. Atualmente utilizo mysql e php sendo requisitado por um script em ajax.

Obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo usar Azure Functions e AXIOS, você pode criar um backend que recebe isto, e enviar usando o AXIOS. Veja  https://github.com/axios/axios e  https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/functions/

Comment: Já tentou pesquisar o firebase?

Comment: Já pensou no `/var/logs/apache2/access.log`?

Comment: +1 no comment do @MagicHat por não querer reinventar a roda =). O registro de cada acesso, com timestamp, ip e user agent já é guardado na log de acessos do seu web server, é só minerar esses dados pra exibir no painel. Pode montar um script PHP que consuma esse arquivo para dentro do mysql a partir do ultimo timestamp processado e agendar no cron pra rodar uma vez por minuto, por exemplo.